# How to check whether an iterator is uninitialized in C++? or compare an iterator against NULL?

Tags: c++, null, iterator, lru, uninitialized-constant

I was implementing LRU Cache in C++.

Here is what the class looks like,

```
class LRUCache {
    private:
        int capacity;
        list<pair<int,int>> memory; // key,value
        unordered_map<int, list<pair<int,int>>::iterator> cache; // key, memAddr
    public:
        LRUCache(int capacity);
        ~LRUCache();
        void insert(int key, int val);
        int query(int key);
        void print();
};
```

For the query method,

```
int LRUCache::query(int key) {
    list<pair<int,int>>::iterator it = cache.at(key);

    // check if 'it' is NULL? or uninitialized and return some arbitrary value to indicate that the key is not found

    memory.erase(it);
    memory.push_front(*it);

    return it->second;
}
```

Have gone through this answer: [Can I check a C++ iterator against null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41352941/can-i-check-a-c-iterator-against-null)
Does not provide a solution for my use case.
It is not possible to compare 'it' against list.end(), since there is no list corresponding to a key NOT FOUND.

How do we check whether `it` is uninitialized?

-- EDIT 1 --

A work around for the specific problem could be by using a conditional statement with `cache.find(key)` against `cache.end()`.

However, why is it not possible to compare against an uninitialized iterator? What is the design philosophy behind it?

Comment: Have you read [std::list::erase](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/erase) iit clearly states : *References and iterators to the erased elements are invalidated. Other references and iterators are not affected.*. Since you erase `it` it is no longer a valid iterator an using it is UB

Comment: Why would `it` ever be uninitialised?! *You* are in charge of inserting the values into your `cache`, so you can ensure that only valid iterators are inserted. If you want to signal absence of an iterator, just delete the entry from the `cache` map! — Or you could also insert a `memory.end()` (and subsequently safely test against that), but I don’t see how that would be useful.

Comment: @RichardCritten In the query method, we are checking if a key is present. If it is not, the corresponding iterator shall be uninitialised.
Hmm, a conditional statement with `cache.find(key)` should work. 
However, why is it not possible to compare against an uninitialized iterator? What is the design philosophy behind it?

Comment: `cache.at(key);` will `throw std::out_of_range{};` if it cannot find the key.

Comment: You could check `find(key) == end()` in order to check if the value is not present.

Comment: @Fareanor yes that is possible.

Comment: Yes, @Eljay. We can handle the exception when `out_of_range` is thrown.

Comment: @KonradRudolph In case where the key is not present in the cache, `it` shall be uninitialized.

Comment: Because an exception is thrown, the iterator will never be constructed (it won't be initialized, it won't be uninitialized... it won't exist at all).

Comment: @Atik No. If `key` is not present in `cache`, `it` will never be initialised because `cache.at(key)` will throw.

Comment: @Atik It's not only for iterators, accessing uninitialized variables is undefined behaviour and you have no way to verify that at runtime. The reason is that it wouldn't make sense to do so. It's up to the developer to write correct code. C++ does not embed all those idiot-proof features because it would surely imply performances overhead which is unwanted. You only pay for what you get. And you will never be able to be completely idiot-proof anyway, it's an infinite run XD But of course, the compiler analyzer will surely emit a warning if it detects an uninitialized variable.

Comment: @Atik you probably want iterators to have some kind of special default-initialised value? That is clearly inefficient idea. Such special case value will make (at least some of) iterator operations to have special checks for that special value in those. Algorithms call operations typically several times over. Meanwhile end() of all containers is required to be O(1). Therefore usage of end() where needed adds only tiny extra effort to caller of algorithm, while special iterator value makes whole algorithm more sluggish.

Comment: @ÖöTiib Yet [forward-iterators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/ForwardIterator) and stronger are required to have such a default value.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat but that value is not used in algorithms because otherwise those should still compare iterators with both one past end and that special value.

Comment: @Atik What's your problem with using a conditional statement with cache.find(key) against cache.end()?